# Jquery scroll down after reaching scroll position

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to scroll down on a page when reaching a certain scroll position. When the user scrolls down a little (100px), jquery should scroll further down.

```
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scrollPos >= 100) {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 300 }, 50);
        } 
    });
```

The code scrolls but get's stuck on scroll position `300`. What is a good way to achieve this without getting stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because on every next scroll, the `scrollPos >= 100` is always true. You have to check if it is the first time user passed over 100.

You can see code below in action in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/veh1qkLt/1/)

```
// just rename it to anything you want
var hasBeenOver100Before = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos >= 100 && !hasBeenOver100Before) {
        // so that on next scroll, code knows this part already executed
        hasBeenOver100Before = true;
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 300 }, 50);
    }

    // reset it to false, so that next time user passes to
    // 100 scrolltop, the code above works again
    if (scrollPos <= 100) hasBeenOver100Before = false;
});
```